# How to show custom formatted text in data bound ListBox control?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms, listbox

How can I show custom formatted text inside ListBox control? ListBox control is bound to data source which reads data from two joined tables. I want to format ListBox item text like this: [UserName, Password]. I want to do this inside .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't custom format the style of the text. However, you can customise the content.

There are many ways to do this. One of them is to bind the data using some SQL query that can achieve what you need, or get the data from database, loop through it and do the modification, and then bind it to the listbox.

Comment: I want to format the content. I think there is a way to achieve this by using DataBinder, but I don't know how.

Comment: Get your data from the database, add it to a list and while you are looping to add it, customise the data, once you are done, use the list to be the data source of the listbox.

Comment: You don't understand. I know how to do it in code behind, but I want to do it inside .aspx page.

Comment: ok, got ya. I do not think that you can handle it with DataBinder. This might help although it is about code behind. http://forums.asp.net/t/1136991.aspx